# Umbraco - how to add a custom notification?

Tags: events, notifications, umbraco

I'm using Umbraco 4.6.2, and need to extend the default notifications it provides. For the sake of this question, let's say I am trying to add an "Unpublish" notification.

In `\umbraco\presentation\umbraco\dialogs\notifications.aspx.cs` it constructs the list of checkbx items shown to the user when opening the "Notifications" dialogue from the context menu.

I see that each `Action` has a ShowInNotifier property - how can I set this value to `true` for the UnPublish action?
Does this require modifying the core codebase, or is there a nice way I can gracefully extend Umbraco?

So after I have added this, users can subscribe to the UnPublish notification (am I missing any steps here?).
Will this automagically send notifications now?

I'm guessing not, so the next thing I have done is hooked the UnPublish event:

```
public class CustomEvents : ApplicationBase
{
    public CustomEvents()
    {
        Document.AfterUnPublish += new Document.UnPublishEventHandler(Document_AfterUnPublish);
    }

    void Document_AfterUnPublish(Document sender, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.UnPublishEventArgs e)
    {
        var user = User.GetCurrent();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email) && user.GetNotifications(sender.Path).Contains("UnPublish"))
        {
            //Send a notification here using default Umbraco settings, or, construct email and send manually:
            string umbracoNotificationSenderAddress = "";   //How to get the address stored in umbracoSettings.config -> <notifications> -> <email>

            //How to use the same subject/message formats used for other notifications? With the links back to the content?
            string subject = "Notification of UnPublish performed on " + MyUtilities.GetFriendlyName(sender.Id);
            string message = MyUtilities.GetFriendlyName(sender.Id) + " has just been unpublished.";

            umbraco.library.SendMail(umbracoNotificationSenderAddress, user.Email, subject, message, true);
        }
    }
}
```

So the bits of that code that are not real/I need some pointers on:

- Is that the correct way for checking if a user is subscribed to a particular notification?
- How can I send a notification using the default umbraco settings? (e.g. generate an email just like the other notifications)

If that is not possible and I must construct my own email:

- How do I get the from email address stored in umbracoSettings.config that
- How can I copy the formatting used by the default Umbraco notifications? Should I manually copy it or is there a nicer way to do this (programmatically).

Any help (or even just links to relevant examples) are appreciated :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague got this working.

Create a class that overrides the action you wish to have notifications for.
You can see all the actions in `/umbraco/cms/Actions`

```
public class ActionUnPublishOverride : umbraco.BusinessLogic.Actions.ActionUnPublish, IAction
{
    ... see what the other actions look like to find out what to put in here!
```

In the overridden class, you will have a `public char Letter`. Set this to match the event to hook into. You can find the letters each event has in the database.

Set the `public bool ShowInNotifier` to true.

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working on Umbraco 4.7 by using the UmbracoSettings class:

http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Content-Management-Systems-CMS/umbraco/umbraco/businesslogic/UmbracoSettings.cs.htm

```
umbraco.library.SendMail(umbraco.UmbracoSettings.NotificationEmailSender, newMember.Email, "email subject", "email body", false);
```

Comment: Right, so this just lets you send emails, but it doesn't use the Umbraco system notifications. That is, it doesn't give users a way to 'subscribe' to certain events. I also already had that exact line in my question :)